# How can I import a Font Awesome icon using the icon name as a string without importing the entire Font Awesome bundle?

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I want to be able to use a Font Awesome icon in a React component by passing the name of the icon to the component as a string. I have it working like this:

```js
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons';
import { fal } from '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons';
import { far } from '@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons';

const Icon = (props: IconProps): ReactElement => {
  if (props.iconPrefix === 'fas') library.add(fas);
  if (props.iconPrefix === 'fal') library.add(fal);
  if (props.iconPrefix === 'far') library.add(far);
  return (
    <div>
        <FontAwesomeIcon
          icon={[props.iconPrefix
            ? props.iconPrefix
            : 'far',
          props.iconName]}
```

I am following roughly [these guidelines](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-font-awesome-5-with-react).

The problem is is that this bloats the minified package size by 4MB but I want a solution where any icon name can be passed as a string without importing the whole library of icons.

What is the solution to this?

Comment: look at this it might help you https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Customize-Font-Awesome